# TSQL - Group By Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have this table that has 2 columns:

```
ID, TypeID
```

Each ID can have multiple TypeIDs. In the query result i want to have the following:

```
ID, Count(TypeID = 10), Count(TypeID = 20 or 30), Count(TypeID 40 and 50)
```

The query itself should be as fast / performant as possible. Can anyon help?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, please edit your post with current data in your table and then the desired result.

Comment: Each ID can have multiple TypeIDs?  Could you post a sample of data?  I think something may have exploded in your database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TypeID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Count of 10",
  SUM(CASE WHEN TypeID IN (20, 30) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Count of 30 or 20",
  SUM(CASE WHEN TypeID IN (40, 50) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Count of 40 AND 50"
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID;
```

For the last case: `Count(TypeID 40 and 50)` I think the predicate `TypeID IN (40, 50)` will work for you, since it will give the count of values 40 and 50.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aab5f/2)

Comment: Good use of aggregates for speed.  +woot.